# Program installation failes

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I recently reinstalled Kubuntu and now when I want to install a software, I see this error:

[image: Error I see]

It happens when I want to install sublime or Emacs. I use Discover software center.

---

Update: Can you please tell me what packages should I check and what should I uncheck?

[image: packages 1]

[image: packages 2]

Comment: Your install medium is still defined as source for packages. As it is most likely not longer in the drive - accessing it fails. Remove the install-medium from your source list. Do that by running `software-properties-gtk` from terminal, jump to the second tab and disable the install-medium as source.

Comment: @dufte sorry for hijacking, but seeing a gtk solution proposed in Kubuntu..I could not resist :-)

Comment: If things are still not working for you, please post the output of `grep -Ev '(^#|^ *$|deb-src)' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

Comment: @Bruni no problem ... my fault ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dufte mentioned in his comment, your install medium is still defined as a source for packages (repository). As it is most likely not longer in the drive - accessing it fails.

To remove the install-medium from your source list, just go to settings in discover and untick the respective entry.

[image]

Comment: Can you please check the update i made in my question? (please check images I added and tell me what packages (sources) I should uncheck).

Comment: @A.Hayati Have you unchecked The one beginning with disc? (the seventh if I see corectly)

Comment: yes it's unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then comment out the line starting with:
`deb cdrom ...`
to be:
`# deb cdrom ...`
Save changes and exit.

Finally run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Can you please check the update i made in my question? (please check images I added and tell me what packages (sources) I should uncheck)